# Is it possible to deploy custom module on ejabberd SaaS

Tags: ejabberd-saas

ejabberd can be extended through an API. How does it work with ejabberd SaaS ?

Can I deploy a module I have developed ? Can I deploy a contributed module ?

Answer (score 2):

ejabberd SaaS is designed to run a standard single platform that is identical for all customers.
As such it does not allow running custom modules (It would be a security risk).

However, it is design to offer API the users can implement to integrate with user backend as needed. There is a simple set of ReST endpoint to implement to be compliant and provide user authentication, contact list or message archive (more are on the way).